# Is there anything special about the single wand in the window of Ollivander's shop?

Tags: harry-potter

> The last shop was narrow and shabby. Peeling gold letters over the door read Ollivanders: Makers of Fine Wands since 382 B.C. ***A single wand lay on a faded purple cushion in the dusty window.***
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter Five - *Diagon Alley*</sub>

Ollivander is well-known and highly respected within the magical community, and the sign above the door seems sufficient to attract Muggle parents to the shop to buy a wand.

Is there anything remarkable about the wand or is it just rather lackluster window dressing?

Comment: You mean more special than being the only wand in the window? IIRC Olivander's shop was rather unimpressive through and through. But when you've got a local monopoly on wands, I guess it doesn't matter much what your store looks like, since everyone will have to come to you anyway.

Comment: @Xantec Yes. I'm wondering if there's any particular reason that *that particular wand* was chosen for display in the window.

Answer (score 6):

From the description, the wand appears to be a display model advertising the contents of the shop.

Per the set-detail photo below (from Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone) there is actually a second wand, similar in length and size sitting on a second identical cushion as well as four wands arranged on [wand display racks](http://www.thefilmcell.com/productimages/Triwizwand_Collection_wand_.jpg) in each window.

The implication from both the book and the film is that these are merely a selection of hand-crafted 'Fine Wands'

[image: Ollivander's]

Answer (score 1):

We don't know anything else about it. A more average story would have used the "Chekov's Gun" approach, and that wand would have some greater significance - it would have been Harry's, or one of his friends, or maybe even Draco's, or possibly even the Elder wand itself. There's also a possibility that there *was* originally a story beyond that wand that was cut from the story during JK's editing process. As far as I know, it hasn't been mentioned in any of the supplementals.